# How to make Javascript Tampermonkey script search for lower AND uppercase characters of same word

Tags: javascript, click, userscripts, tampermonkey, case-insensitive

I currently have a Tampermonkey-based JS userscript that automatically clicks certain buttons if they are associated with a specified string of text, but right now it only senses capital OR lowercase letters, and not both at the same time. I want the script to be able to work even if the word starts with a capital letter or not.

Here is the code I have been working with:

```
const findAndClickParent = text => [...document.querySelectorAll('label > span')].forEach(e => e.textContent === "Male" ? e.parentElement.click(): null);

waitForKeyElements (
  "label",
  () => {
    findAndClickParent("Male");
  }
);
```

So this script automatically clicks a radio button with the word "Male" in it. However, I want it to also be able to click a radio button with lowercase "male," as well. Seems like a simple solution, but I haven't been able to find the syntax to pull it off yet. Any and all advice would be much appreciated. Have a great day/night!

Comment: Is the requirement for an exact match of `"Male"`, case insensitive? Should "female" or "maler" be matched?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was thinking male, specifically, here. I just want the script to basically autofill any instance of "male," regardless of case. I think it would be cool to be able to be able to recognize anything with the string "male" in it too, like both (fe)male and male. Do you happen to know how to carry any of that out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lowercase the `textContent` as well as the passed `text` before comparing:

```
const findAndClickParent = text => {
  const lowerText = text.toLowerCase();
  [...document.querySelectorAll('label > span')]
    .forEach((e) => {
      if (e.textContent.toLowerCase() === lowerText) {
        e.parentElement.click();
      }
    });
}

waitForKeyElements(
  "label",
  () => {
    findAndClickParent("Male");
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `RegExp` literal or constructor with `i` flag set and `RegExp.prototype.test()`

```
/male/i.test(e.textContent)
```